# checkedIcon and uncheckedIcon under radio button in material ui are both being triggered?

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I have a following code:

```
const PlatformRadioButton = ({onPlatform}) => (
<div>
<RadioButtonGroup style={{ display: 'flex', maxWidth: 100}} 
                  name="platform" 
                  defaultSelected="9" 
                  onChange={(e,v) => onPlatform(v)} >
  <RadioButton 
    value="9"
    checkedIcon={<PlatformIcon platform="ios" color="blue" />}
    uncheckedIcon={<PlatformIcon platform="ios" color="gray" />}
    style={styles.radioButton}
  />
</RadioButtonGroup>
</div>
);

export default PlatformRadioButton;
```

and the other piece of code is this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

const PlatformIcon = (props) => {
let platform = props.platform, 
    color = props.color;
if (platform == "all"){
    platform = "ios_android";
}
var imgPath = "/static/img/banner_toggle_" + platform + "_" + color +      ".png";

return <img src={imgPath} />
}

export default PlatformIcon;
```

Not sure..why both checkedIcon and uncheckedIcon are being triggered at the same time..I feel like I am missing a piece of code..could someone shed a light on this please..

Comment: So after some more research, i found out that using the icon given by the Material UI site works well with the given code...